# inner.html / handlers

Tags: javascript, html

as an incoming javascript coder, i'm stuck at a sample exercise...

```html
<script language="JavaScript">
  var num1;
  var messages;
  var answer = document.getElementById("guess").value;
  var counter = 0;
  answer = Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * 32);

  function start() {
    var button = document.getElementById("guessButton");
    button.addEventListener("click", Myguess, false);
  };

  function Myguess() {
    num1 = document.getElementById("guess").value;
    do {
      if (num1 == answer) {
        messages.innerHTML = "Ahah!"
      }
      if (num1 < answer) {
        messages.innerHTML = "Either you know the secer or you got lucky!";
      }
      if (num1 > answer) {
        messages.innerHTML = "you should be able to do better";
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<body>
  <form action="#">
    <input id="guessButton" type="button" value="guess">
    <input id="inputfield" type="number" value="guess a number 1- 32">
  </form>
</body>
```

this is supposed to print:

- `number of guesses is 5 or fewer: "either you know the secret or you got lucky"`
- Or `number of guesses is 5 or more:"you should be able to do better"`
- Or `number of guesses in 5 tries : "ahah!"`

however it's not printing `.../././`

Comment: Is `Start` running on document load? You shouldn't use `do`, Just get rid of it and the code will work.

Comment: Code seems to be missing here. 1) Where's your `messages` element?

Comment: ibrahim mahrir i tried that, and it's the same problem

Comment: You need a while statement to go with your do loop.

Answer (score 1):

Initially there are few syntax errors to correct

- `do {}` without while is not valid javascript.
- start() is never called. I'm guessing you intended to use `window.onload = start` or `<body onload="start();">`
- Your script is executed before the HTML elements it is modifying. If you want to access elements from the DOM you should access them within a function and/or place the script at the bottom of the body tag.
- `<script language="JavaScript">` is deprecated. I think you mean `<script type="text/javascript">` although as that is the default the type is optional.
- The messages variable is never assigned
- You set text as the value to a number input. I suspect you intended to use `placeholder="guess a number 1- 32"`. Note that placeholder is actually used to provide a hint about expected input. Direct instructions should use a label. This doesn't affect your javascript but is worth considering all the same.

Additionally myGuess() currently checks if the submitted value is less than the answer or more. You need to increment a count value and compare against that.

The below example do what you need

```html
<form action="#">
   <label for="inputfield">guess a number 1-32</label>
   <input id="guessButton" type="button" value="guess">
   <input id="inputfield" type="number">
  </form>
  <p id="messages"></p>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   var num1;
            var target = 5;
   var messages = document.getElementById("messages");
   var counter = 0;
   var answer = Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * 32);

   function start() {
    var button = document.getElementById("guessButton");
    button.addEventListener("click", Myguess, false);
   };

   function Myguess() {
    num1 = document.getElementById("inputfield").value;
                if(num1 == answer) {
       if (counter === target) {
      messages.innerHTML = "Ahah!"
     }
     if (counter < target) {
      messages.innerHTML = "Either you know the secer or you got lucky!";
     }
     if (counter > target) {
      messages.innerHTML = "you should be able to do better";
     }
                } else {
                 counter++;
     messages.innerHTML = "Keep trying";
                }
   }

   window.onload = start;
  </script>
```

Comment: why is there do / while but not do?

Comment: do/while is a loop condition. It says "do this while the condition is true". Without while there is no condition telling it when to execute the do block

Comment: -number of guesses is 5 or fewer: "either you know the secret or you got lucky"
-Or number of guesses is 5 or more:"you should be able to do better"
-Or number of guesses in 5 tries : "ahah!"


like i dont want the messages to show before hitting 5, or the person get the right number

Comment: Ah sorry. I got caught up in the syntax errors and missed that. You just need to increment a counter and compare that against your target number of guessed. I've updated the answer to address it now.

Answer (score 0):

The code you need is this:

```
<body>
  <form id="form">
    <input id="guessButton" type="submit" value="guess">
    <input id="inputfield" type="number" placeholder="guess a number 1-32">
  </form>
  <div id="messages"></div>
  <span id="counter"></span> tries
</body>

<script language="JavaScript">

  document.getElementById('form').onsubmit = function() {
    return Myguess();
  };

  var num1;
  var messages = document.getElementById("messages");
  var counterDiv = document.getElementById("counter");
  counterDiv.innerHTML = 0;
  var counter = 0;
  answer = Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * 32);

  function Myguess() {

    num1 = document.getElementById("inputfield").value;
    if (num1 == answer) {
      messages.innerHTML = "Ahah!"
    }
    if (num1 < answer) {
      messages.innerHTML = "Either you know the secer or you got lucky!";
    }
    if (num1 > answer) {
      messages.innerHTML = "you should be able to do better";
    }
    counter++;
    counterDiv.innerHTML = counter;

    return false;

  }

</script>
```

You can test it in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nhdhdasw/1/).

The function Myguess() is called when the form is submitted. There was no div messages missing in your code, so I added it. I also added the counter span which shows how many tries the player has had. Also the message "guess a number 1-32" is better added as placeholder. I hope that was helpful !

Comment: logically i dont think this looks right;

its supposed to output the messeage when they guess the message in less the, on , or more 5 tries

Comment: I don't get it. Do you mean message that says eg "you should be able to do better"? When do you want to print it? It is printed every time the player presses the guess button or presses enter. Also, I corrected the JSFiddle link. You can test it there.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script language="JavaScript">
  var num1;
  var messages; // should be initialized inside start because at this moment it doen't exist
  var answer;
  var counter = 0;
  answer = Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * 32);

  window.addEventListener("load", start); // on loading the page call start;

  function start() {
    messages = document.getElementById("message"); // this should be something
    
    var button = document.getElementById("guessButton");
    button.addEventListener("click", Myguess, false);
  };

  function Myguess() {
    num1 = document.getElementById("inputfield").value; // the id is "inputfield" not "guess"
    if (num1 == answer) {
      messages.innerHTML = "Ahah!"
    }
    // else if to stop checking again (if is correct but not the best)
    else if (num1 < answer) {
      messages.textContent = "Either you know the secer or you got lucky!";  //textContent is better than innerHTML
    }
    // same here
    else if (num1 > answer) {
      messages.innerHTML = "you should be able to do better";
    }
  }
</script>

<body>
  <form action="#">
    <input id="guessButton" type="button" value="guess">
    <input id="inputfield" type="number" value="guess a number 1- 32">
  </form>
  <div id="message"></div>
</body>
```

**Note:** you was using `do`-`while` incorrectly (you was messing the `while` part). Anyway, `do`-`while` or any other loop will just loop forever if the answer is not correct because you are not letting the user to re-enter a number. What you need is to check whether the number is correct or not whenevr the user click the button (that parts you had it correct because you used the event listener).

What your code was doing (or supposed to be doing) is check if a user clicks the button and then loop if his answer was incorrect untill the answer is is correct (which is not going to happen because you never give the user another chance to enter a number again. He will get a chance after the function execution is finished. And because of the loop it will never be finished). It was never going to work because the loop waits for the user to enter another number (a correct one) to exit and the user is waiting for the loop to end to enter another number (see the paradox).

What it should do is to wait for the user to enter a number, check that number, prints the message accordingly for that number and then give the user to enter another number. (It is a loop (cycle) already so why need another loop)